# Getting patterns out of a binary string

Tags: matlab, binary-tree

I have a binary string of length `N` which is a power of 2 (`N = 2^n`).

I need to extract specific patterns of length `L` which is a power of `2` (`L = 2^l`).

In a **full binary tree**, these patterns should

- start with a left leaf node (even index) and
- end with a right leaf node (odd index).

These patterns should include leaves of an **entire subtree**. 
Patterns I need to extract are,

```
(1). 0 0 --- 0  (All zero)
(2). 1 1 --- 1  (All one)
(3). 0 0 --- 1  (Only the last right leaf is one).
```

For example, if I have a binary string of `N=16`, (`n=4`) such as
 `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0` ,  I need to extract

- indices `0 to 7` as pattern (3),
- indices `8 to 11` as pattern (2) and
- last `4` indices as pattern (1).

I need this as a part of a channel decoding algorithm, to prune the binary tree. Is there an efficient method to do this in Matlab?

Comment: Have you tried actually building that tree and recursively evaluating branches?

Comment: To further clarify, these patterns can exist anywhere in the string. But each pattern should start from the leftmost leaf of a subtree and end with the rightmost leaf of the subtree.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I added the code I where I implemented this recursively.

Comment: That is good code, I'm not sure how to significantly improve on that. I would recommend that you don't do `pattern3_indices = [pattern3_indices ; [st,ed]];`, but use `pattern3_indices(end+1,:) = [st,ed];` instead, which is typically faster. Any you might want to add `all` to `if chunk == pattern3`: `if all(chunk == pattern3)`. `all` is applied by default there, but it's nice to be explicit about it (I'm always looking up what the behaviour of `if` with an array is).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you!. Will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the solution recursively as below,

```
s = [0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1 ];
N=length(s);
n = log2(N);

mask = zeros(1,N);
pattern1_indices = [];
pattern2_indices = [];
pattern3_indices = [];


for l= n:-1:1
    L = 2^l;
    t  = 2^(n-l); % Number of strings of size L

    pattern1= zeros(1,L);
    pattern3= pattern1;
    pattern3(end) = 1;
    pattern2 = ones(1,L);

    for i = 1:t
        st = (i-1)*L+1 ;
        ed = i*L ; 
        if(mask(st)==1)
            continue
        end
        chunk =  s(st:ed) ;

        if chunk == pattern3 % Only the last bit is one
            mask(st:ed) = 1;
            pattern3_indices = [pattern3_indices ; [st,ed]];
        elseif chunk == pattern1
            mask(st:ed) = 1; % All zero
            pattern1_indices = [pattern1_indices ; [st,ed]];
        elseif chunk == pattern2
            mask(st:ed) = 1; % All one
            pattern2_indices = [pattern2_indices ; [st,ed]];
        end         
    end
end
```

I get the start and end indices of each pattern as below,

```
pattern1_indices

pattern1_indices =

     []

>> pattern2_indices

pattern2_indices =

    15    16
    23    24
    27    28
    31    32

>> pattern3_indices

pattern3_indices =

     1     4
     5     8
     9    12
    17    20
    13    14
    21    22
    25    26
    29    30
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the most simple solution will be to use a [regular expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) with `regexp`

```
%binary string example
s = '0000000111110000'

%Get the start Index (SI) and the end Index (EI)
[SI,EI] = regexp(s,'0+$')       %pattern 1
[SI,EI] = regexp(s,'0+1')       %pattern 2
[SI,EI] = regexp(s,'(?<!0)1+')  %pattern 3
```

Noticed that index on matlab start with 1 and not 0.

You can also use multiple regular expression at once:

```
[SI,EI] = regexp(s,{'0+$','0+1','(?<!0)1+'})
```

**Result:**

```
SI = 
{
  [1,1] =  13
  [1,2] =  1
  [1,3] =  9
}
EI = 
{
  [1,1] =  16
  [1,2] =  8
  [1,3] =  12
}
```

Comment: This does not include the positional requirements for substrings.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't get your comment can you please elaborate ?

Comment: OP asks for substrings that occupy a full branch in the binary tree representation of the string. Thus a 2-element substring must start at an 1, 3, 5, etc. A 4-element substring must start at 1, 4, 8, etc. And you can’t have a 3-element substring. Or at least this is how I interpret that. :)

Comment: Ho ok thanks, I understand now :) Yeah, ok you're right, I've missed that. I'm going to edit my answer.